# scrollTop of element always returns 0

Tags: javascript

Im trying to log how far down the page an element is, but in my console I keep getting 0.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  var selector = document.getElementById("footer");

  console.log(selector.scrollTop );

});
```

From reading about this there seems to be a webkit bug if the body has an overflow or height applied it. However Ive tried this in IE and Firefox, and with all my CSS disabled and I keep getting the same result.

Comment: Isn't `scrollTop` how far you've scrolled in the element? If there's no scrollbar and you're not scrolling within the element, then it will always be 0.

Comment: For example, if you make a div and set it to `overflow-y: scroll`, then when you scroll WITHIN that div, its scrollTop will change. Otherwise, only the `body`'s scrollTop will change.

Comment: Sorry, I will remove my answer, I didn't see that is pure javascript, not jquery, and the answer of jossef is fine (the same than mine but without jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `offsetTop` instead.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  var selector = document.getElementById("footer");

  console.log(selector.offsetTop);

});
```

---

**Online demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/JdeFnB6IZodL0b74pO2S?p=preview**

- check the console output, iv'e set an interval to trigger the print

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

For element position relative to page top, I'd use:

```
console.log(selector.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset);
```

For element position relative to viewport top, I'd use:

```
console.log(selector.getBoundingClientRect().top);
```

Documentation:

- [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)
- [pageYOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)

As mentioned by Michael Zhang in the comments, `selector.scrollTop` tells you how many pixels the element itself has been scrolled ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)).

`selector.offsetTop` is the number of pixels from the top of the closest relatively positioned parent element ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)).